# FFmpeg: Can you use -map to select streams based on codec?

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg: I know that I can use the `-map` option to select streams either by index or by, at least, the language metadata.

I have some video files that contain both text (srt) and graphical (dvd_subtitle) subtitles. During re-encoding these files, I want to copy *only* the srt subtitles.

The ordering of the subtitles in the original containers is inconsistent, so selecting subtitles on index is not feasible.

Can this be done with the `-map` command?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options), there is no option to map by codec. I think you better use a Python script that uses FFprobe output in JSON format, and find the stream number by the codec. With [ffmpeg-python](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/), it's a bit simpler: `dict = ffmpeg.probe(filename)`

Comment: I ended up doing just that with Python. I was going to do it as a shell script but I just know Python much better and it's still a perfectly viable command line scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at present, with `-map`. It's on my to-do, but on the backburner for now.